# is it possible to import a node package from another package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules

Let's say I just recently installed `react-native-gifted-chat` from npm, and I realized there is another package inside it, how do I access `uuid` package in that package?

this is inside my node_module folder:

[image: This is inside my node_modules folder]

Regularly we just do `import ... from 'react-native-gifted-chat'`, to access package but how to access `uuid` package inside `react-native-gifted-chat` **without installing** `uuid` package?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is: Why do you want this?

I believe that the correct approach should be to depend on `uuid` directly, if you actually depend on it.

There is no guarantee that future versions of `react-native-gifted-chat` will depend on `uuid`, or depend on a version that has the same interface you're expecting.

Also, I believe that npm makes some effort to deduplicate the same versions of packages depended on by multiple things, so you shouldn't concern yourself overly about disk space.

Answer (score 1):

well, I think the best way is to install the wanted packages as new separate packages with npm, because maybe in the future, the devs of `react-native-gifted-chat` may stop depending on that package, and you will get errors that may drive you crazy before realizing the mistake you have done, so you better install `uuid` as a new dependency in your project so you will never have to worry about it being removed from `react-native-gifted-chat`.

Hope i was clear, thanks